# Bug API migration with postgreSQL

Tags: drush, migrations

i have an issue concerning the API migration.
I have an existing drupal 7 website with a MySQL database.
Now i want to migrate this website in a new drupal 8 instalation with a postgreSQL database.
With a drupal 8 postgreSql, i can't execute the drush commande "migrate-status" or other :  [image]

while with exactly the same module and config, simply changing the BDD by a mySql one, i have access to these commands : [image]

Does the migration modules are compatible with a postgresSql drupal ?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply don't have the migrate_tools module enabled in the Postgres environment.

Comment: Hello Mike, actually i have exactly the same module enabled in both environment. That's why i don't really understand.
Regards,